# Database Accuracy Check

Tags: dataset, accuracy

I will be collecting a large amount of data over a long period of time by running a cron job to continually scrape a website daily. Because of the sheer volume of data being gathered, it is not efficient to check every single data point. Is there some mathematical way to ensure a certain amount of confidence that my database will be x% correct? Perhaps, randomly sample from the database and just check the data in the sample?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that all the data points are originally sampled independently, and you want to know what proportion are correct, then you have the problem of estimating a binomial proportion. Take a random subsample and count how many are correct to get your number of trials and observed successes. There are various kinds of [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) for this quantity. Of course, your best point estimate of the true proportion will just be the proportion you observe in your subsample.